# Flat UI ProのRailsへのインストールで bower install がエラーになる

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Flat UI Proデザインフレームワークを [reflection/designmodo-flatuipro-rails](https://github.com/reflection/designmodo-flatuipro-rails) を使って、Rails4.2のプロジェクトにインストールしようとしています。
rails generate flatuipro:install すると、下記のエラーが出ます。

```
$ rails generate flatuipro:install ~/flat-ui-pro
/Users/maimai/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/designmodo-flatuipro-rails-1.3.2.0.branch/lib/generators/flatuipro/install/install_generator.rb:25:in `copy_assets': 'bower install' must be run first to fetch javascript dependencies (RuntimeError)
```

'bower install' must be run...と表示されたので、'bower install'したのですが、こちらも下記のようにエラーとなりインストールできません。

```
$ bower install
bower                           ENOENT No bower.json present
```

bower install がエラーになる原因は何でしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以下のサイトに手順が載っています。

Step1の最後で bower install が実行されています。
bower.jsonファイルが有るディレクトリに移動して、bower install する必要があるのでは？

参考サイト
http://joanswork.com/add-flat-ui-pro-to-rails/

Comment: ありがとうございます。bower installできました！
rails generate flatuipro:install ~/flat-ui-proコマンド後にまたエラーが出てしまいました。どうしたら良いでしょうか